# Restored a crashed server from a image copy almost 8 months old and

Tags: windows-server-2008, internal-dns, mirror, drive

This was a DC, I also have BDC. Got the Ransomware virus on the server. It was too much work, so I mirrored an 8 month old drive and got the server back up, restored the data from backup, but

1. this server will not sync up at all to my BDC.
2. My network is seeing this as the gateway.
3. My network is seeing this as the DNS server. NO INTERNET..
4. Tombstone messages of course.
5. Server not getting out to the internet no matter what IP/DNS settings I put in there which is very strange..

Multiple issues going on here. Where should I start.

My network logins are little flaky to because of this. If I set the network PC's to my BDC's DNS, then of course internet works fine, but doesn't on the PDC..

Need some guidance.

Answer (score 4):

> Multiple issues going on here. Where should I start.

1. Shut down and delete the restored DC.
2. Perform whatever metadata cleanup is needed to remove the restored DC from AD.
3. Sieze the FSMO roles to the other DC.
4. Build a new DC to replace the restored DC.
5. Never restore an 8 month old DC ever again.
6. Stop calling them PDC and BDC.
7. Implement a legitimate backup scheme and schedule for your DC's and whatever else you need to backup and potentially restore.
8. Profit!